# Can I find which user ran a command using su?

Tags: linux, su

Can I find who did run a command as a super user?
I have the process ID and the super user id, but not the underlying human user.

Comment: Grep in /var/log? Depends on your distripution but maybe [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108577/how-to-log-commands-within-a-sudo-su) helps.

Comment: this seems to belong to superuser of linux...

Answer (score 0):

Unless the command generate some specific logging you will not be able to know if it was run or not and by whom. AFAIK, in Linux there's not such logging for every command run in the system. I think, the only way you may see if some user has run the command is to search in his history (.history file) and see if the command was launched and whether it was launched using sudo or su. But this relies in the user history which only stored the last 500 lines by default (its configurable through the HISTFILESIZE variable)

Additionally, there are other methods to launch a command as super user so looking just for su/sudo is not enough. Take a look to the following link for more info on the different methods to launch a command as root:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/

Comment: I mean can I check who ran a PID ?